# ASP.NET Core model state does not return DataMember name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core, modelstate

When using the following model

```
[DataContract]
public class MyModel 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "email_address")]
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

When I use `ModelState` in my controller action it validates correctly if I don't supply the required parameters it returns

```
{
    "Name": [
        "The Name field is required."
    ],
    "EmailAddress": [
        "The EmailAddress field is not a valid e-mail address."
    ]
}
```

However, as you can see the external key to the property Name is 'name' and EmailAddress is 'email_address' but I am getting the property name returned instead.

How do you get the ModelState errors to adhere to the DataMember name? I don't want to return the property name in snake case or camel case, I want to use the DataMember name.

## Update

I have raised an issue on aspnet repo: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6942

Answer (score -1):

[`DataMemberAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) is used by `DataContractSerializer`. Use [`DisplayNameAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[DataMember(Name = "email_address")]
[DisplayName("email_address")]
[Required]
[EmailAddress]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Comment: Unfortunatly that doen't work, neither does `[Display(Name = "email_address")]`

Comment: Try `[Required(ErrorMessage = "The name field is required.")]`

Comment: unfortunately the result key is still the name of the field `{ "EmailAddress": [ "The email_address field is required." ] }` so that doesn't help. The consumer of the api should be able to find the error for a field based on the key they sent in the first place. This implementation for model state does not seem to be fit for purpose so I have raised an issue on aspnet  repo https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6942